# Why is Web Deploy giving me an error code 0x800704CD

Tags: iis-7, webmatrix, webdeploy

I'm trying to get Web Deploy to work from Web Matrix and I've searched through through all the logs and events and can't seem to find the source of the following error in the event viewer:

```
Log Name:      Microsoft Web Deploy
Source:        Web Deploy
Date:          9/4/2013 1:48:16 PM
Event ID:      1
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          XXX
Computer:      XX
Description:
User: 
Client IP: 
Content-Type: 
Version: 9.0.0.0
MSDeploy.VersionMin: 7.1.600.0
MSDeploy.VersionMax: 9.0.1762.0
MSDeploy.Method: GetPackage
MSDeploy.RequestId: 4cab8a9b-5c5c-4f99-8141-52e5453b88f9
MSDeploy.RequestCulture: en-US
MSDeploy.RequestUICulture: en-US
ServerVersion: 9.0.1762.0
Skip: objectName="^configProtectedData$"
Provider: iisApp, Path: xxx.xxx.xxx
A tracing deployment agent exception occurred that was propagated to the client. Request ID '4cab8a9b-5c5c-4f99-8141-52e5453b88f9'. Request Timestamp: '9/4/2013 1:48:15 PM'. Error Details:
System.Web.HttpException: The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD.
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.FlushWrite()
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Flush()
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.PackageSerializer.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleGetPackage(DeploymentAgentWorkerRequest workerRequest)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequestWorker(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequest(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)

Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Web Deploy" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-09-04T17:48:16.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>238</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Microsoft Web Deploy</Channel>
    <Computer>xxxx</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-3588641846-14347574-4076679054-500" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>User: 
Client IP: 
Content-Type: 
Version: 9.0.0.0
MSDeploy.VersionMin: 7.1.600.0
MSDeploy.VersionMax: 9.0.1762.0
MSDeploy.Method: GetPackage
MSDeploy.RequestId: 4cab8a9b-5c5c-4f99-8141-52e5453b88f9
MSDeploy.RequestCulture: en-US
MSDeploy.RequestUICulture: en-US
ServerVersion: 9.0.1762.0
Skip: objectName="^configProtectedData$"
Provider: iisApp, Path: xxx.xxx.xxx
A tracing deployment agent exception occurred that was propagated to the client. Request ID '4cab8a9b-5c5c-4f99-8141-52e5453b88f9'. Request Timestamp: '9/4/2013 1:48:15 PM'. Error Details:
System.Web.HttpException: The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x800704CD.
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ExplicitFlush()
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.Flush(Boolean finalFlush)
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.FlushWrite()
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Flush()
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.PackageSerializer.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleGetPackage(DeploymentAgentWorkerRequest workerRequest)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequestWorker(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequest(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I used Web Deploy on the server to create the settings file using IIS on the host.  This error appears during the simple web page compatibility test.  Any clues as to what may be going on?

Comment: This error comes for me during an Azure web app deploy, thus I'm not in control of the server.

Answer (score 0):

The error is basically because the remote server, or the hosting service provider **closed the request.**

Sometimes it is also stated as the server is trying to deny or is try to cancel the requests. For instance, a user started to download some file or a page, and the server is off so the download would be cancelled, or the download would fail.

There are many issues for this error code.

Here is a post from another forum. [forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1725135.aspx/1)

The best method would be to check the settings on the server that you are having hosting from. Or contact them directly to get help regarding this issue.

**Edit:**

**Getting LogFiles:**

You can get the LogFiles here:

start --> run --> LogFiles

2011-09-20 21:25:25 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx 36482 192.168.10.32 80 HTTP/1.1 POST /orders/mail/mailorderentry - - Timer_HeaderWait –

2011-09-20 21:22:29 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx 44399 192.168.10.32 80 HTTP/1.1 POST /orders/mail/mailorderentry - - Client_Reset –

**HttpRunTime:**

Secondly the request closed issue can also raise if the httpRunTime is out (timeout). But that exception isn't here I am sure, however still try this too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx

**Antivirus (If any):**

Also, please try check if Antivirus is installed, then is it allowing the server to communicate with users or not? Sometimes along with Firewall, Antivirus might also try to stop the connections.

Comment: I am in complete control of the server.  Is there a place to look for where such information is logged.

Comment: I am not sure for where this setting is present. But I can tell you where you get the perfect and IIS related help. Try it here on there forum. [http://forums.iis.net/t/1149787.aspx](http://forums.iis.net/t/1149787.aspx) or this thread [http://forums.iis.net/t/1178528.aspx](http://forums.iis.net/t/1178528.aspx). The IIS forum will help you in learning about IIS errors and events,

Comment: Sorry, but I tried those forums.  If they were any good, SO wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: please reread the answer, i hope the three items would help you now!

Comment: This error comes for me during an Azure web app deploy, thus I'm not in control of the server.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the exact same eventLogs, after the webmatrix web deploy throwed a "can not publish" (without any apparent reasons because it worked several month so far).

After some searches (unlucky) and a lot of fumbling, I got it to work again just by **using a windows user with administrator privileges instead of the IIS Manager Users configuration**.

Comment: LOL! Yeah, what's the point of Microsoft's security if it so complex, people just turn it off.